# Use "In this regard" in this specific context

Tags: word-usage, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

> Note that for the above theorem no specific assumptions are made on subjects 1 and 2. In this regard, the following result can be given.
>   Result: ....

'Result' can be seen as a corollary (of the theorem) in which some assumptions regarding subjects 1 and 2 are made.

Is the above usage of `in this regard` correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an idiomatic expression that means the same thing as "given this information" or "from this point of view".  Example:

> The young man came from extreme poverty where no one in his family had even graduated high school much less university.  In this regard, the fact that he was able to get his PhD. in Mathematics before the age of 22 was nothing short of extraordinary.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused.. Am I using the expression correctly ? The only thing that confuses me is that in the Theorem I don't make assumptions on Subjects 1 and 2, whereas in the Corrollary I am make such assumptions. So, `in this regard` is used to (kind of) link two opposite ideas. Is it fine ?

Comment: It doesn't really indicate an *opposite* idea as much as additional information that contributes to the conclusion.  In the above example it's hard to tell since I don't understand the context, but you might use a different expression that indicates *contrast*, like "in contrast" or "on the other hand" or " alternately" or "despite this"